# Get Room Types in a hotel

Tags: sabre

I am developing a reservation system for hotels with Sabre Dev Studio. I want to propose different available Hotels around a location... I use the OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ request in Sabre SOAP API. I have a list of hotels and rooms with prices.

But, at that moment, I'd like to show my end-user the room description, the photos, the room type name (i.e. "Double confort room", "Junior Suite", etc). It seems Sabre does not give any of those informations : a price, an unusable description... that's all ?

Could anyone explain me if any Sabre SOAP API request can give me these informations (I already tried the HotelImage rq, but it gives general hotel images, not a given room type image list) ???

regards

Comment: Where you able to find an answer? I am currently trying to do the same thing and the sabre room descriptions are very bizzare. The names are not usually very human readable, and definitely not fit for a website. We have resulted in writing a parser to try and make it readable. Any luck on your side?

Answer (score 1):

For getting a specific detailed description of Hotel, you need to call an API that can give you such information like:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/hotel/search/hotel_property_description

There are other Hotel Description services published on Dev Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Sabre doesn't provide any room data. However it provides some clues for matching roomrates to rooms. The IATA_CharacteristicIdentification is typically a combination of a rate and a room. For example, say a particlar hotel has a roomrate of "A03LV2" which might be for a rate A03 and a room LV2. You can then match all the roomrates that end in LV2 to a particular room. As for the name of the room, often there is something of a description in the AdditionalInfo->TEXT objects.